# Как достать значения с PromiseResult?

Tags: javascript, python, html, eel

Решено!

Пишу веб приложения на Python и HTML, библиотека eel.
Когда я хочу получить значения з пайтоновской функции то я получаю Promise. С JS почти никогда не работал
Код JS:

```
async function get_books() {
    return await eel.bookstore()();
}

let res = get_books();
console.log(res);
```

Код Python:

```
@eel.expose
def bookstore():
    return 222
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
let res = await get_books(); // дожидаемся ответа
```